# script dosen't execute ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending ajax request to the file, but for some reason the file doesn't complete operation, I know that request reaches the file, because it echoes request received, and it stops there. I can't figure out why.

```
<?php
 /**
* Created by PhpStorm.
* Date: 23.2.2015.
* Time: 5:20
* Version 1.1
*/
    $nacin_rada = 'echo';//promjenjivo u session
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');
    $year = date("Y");

    echo 'request received';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   //get_magic_quotes_gpc removed in php 5.4.0
        $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
        $password = stripslashes(md5($_POST['password']));
        $passverif = stripslashes(md5($_POST['passverif']));
        $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
        $ime = stripslashes($_POST['ime']);
        $prezime = stripslashes($_POST['prezime']);
        $dan = stripslashes($_POST['dan']);
        $mjesec = stripslashes(intval($_POST['mjesec']));
        $godina = stripslashes(intval($_POST['godina']));
        $avatar_source = stripslashes($_POST['avatar']);
        $sex = stripslashes($_POST['sex']);


        if ($sex == 'žensko' and $avatar_source == '') {

                $avatar_source = 'default_profile_female.jpeg'; //potrebno dodati podršku za default sliku

        } elseif ($sex == 'muško' and $avatar_source == '') {

            $avatar_source = 'default_profile_male.jpeg'; //potrebno dodati podršku za default sliku
        }


        if ($username == '' or $password == '' or $passverif == '' or $email == '' or $ime == '' or $prezime == '' or $dan == '' or $mjesec == '' or $godina == '' or $avatar_source == '') {
            echo ' You didn\'t fill out all the forms';
            exit;
        }

        if ($password <= 2) {
            echo 'Password too short';
            exit;
        }


        if ($passverif <= 2) {
            echo 'Password verification too short';
            exit;
        }

        if ($password != $passverif) {
            echo 'Va&#353;e lozinke se ne podudaraju';
            exit;
        }

        if ($mjesec > '12' or $mjesec < '1') {
            echo $mjesec . 'nije valjani izbor';
            exit;

        }

        if ($godina > $year) {  //year defined at line 12
            echo 'Vi ste iz budu&#269;nosti?';
            exit;
        }

        if ($godina == '0000') {
            echo '0000 nije valjani izbor';
            exit;
        }


        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die("Query Failed");// redefining sql query for user data selection
        $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if ($num_row >= 1) {
            echo '<span style="color:white;">U bazi podataka ve&#269; postoji ra&#269;un s tim Emailom</span>';
        } elseif ($num_row == 0) {

            $insert_users = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, ime, prezime,sex, avatar, dan, mjesec, godina) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$ime','$prezime','$sex','$avatar_source','$dan','$mjesec','$godina')");
            $insert_user_data = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO user_data(hometown, love_status, about) VALUES ('NULL','NULL','NULL' )");
            echo 'Registracija uspje&scaron;na,mo&#382;ete se <a href="login.php">prijaviti</a>';
        } else echo 'Registracija neuspjela';


    } 
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the developer tools to see if it's returning an error code?

Comment: Do you using proper type of ajax call? POST?

Comment: Try to var_dump $_POST, you've a condition on the 'submit' index if it's not sent in POST the rest of the code won't be executed

Comment: you can use the "basic method". Each 5 lines or each some specific sentence put `echo "break1"; .... echo "break2";` if you receive the echo this means that the code breaks after the echo not before xD

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6m0rfm is my ajax script,how do u you mean var_dump@ThierryGirod ?

Comment: In the ajax call, is `data: {username,password,passverif,email,...}` the proper formatting?

Comment: @nada echo dosent work if inside submit condition

Comment: so you aren't sending $_POST['submit'] from the ajax call. Make sure you are sending something or change it to other constant var or just isset($_POST['username'])

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles yes,there is no spelling mistake

Comment: @nada dosent work either

Comment: do what @ThierryGirod said and show us the result. Maybe you're passing nothing to $_POST. If ajax call not working try to use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Comment: array(1) {
  ["{username,password,passverif,email,ime,prezime,dan,mjesec,godina,avatar_source,sex}"]=>
  string(0) ""
} @nada

Comment: POST['submit'] isn't defined.

Comment: read @bloodyKnuckles answer sir

Comment: You're using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) against. You're using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and should [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of  passwords.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery ajax method, data parameter takes, among other things, an object, such as:

```
data: { username: username, password: password, passverif: passverif, email: email ... }
```

You're passing:

```
data: "{username,password,passwordverif,email...}"
```

A couple things that don't work there: 1) not `key: value` pairs, and 2) that's a string, not an object.

Another problem, these:

```
var username = $('.username').val;
```

...need to be changed to:

```
var username = $('.username').val();
```

Notice the parenthesis at the end.

---

So you have 3 things to fix. Two in your JavaScript, and one in your PHP file.

JavaScript:

1. Use object notation in `data` setting.
2. Don't quote that object.

PHP:

1. Use something other than `$_POST['submit']` to check for form data on your server script.

Comment: data: "{username: username, password: password,  passverif: passverif, email: email, ime: ime, prezime: prezime, dan: dan, mjesec: mjesec, godina: godina, avatar_source: avatar_source, sex: sex}"

treied without qoutes,same result,nothing,not even echo outside if submit

Comment: Be sure to also fix what @MHakvoort pointed out in his answer, change `$_POST['submit']` to `$_POST['username']`.

Comment: i did,and got no response from file,not even echo that worked before.

Comment: It's easy to overlook, but important: do not wrap your data object in quotes. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You had several errors:

In your AJAX call use this way to send the parameters, like bloodyKnuckles pointed out:

```
data: { username: username, password: password, passverif: passverif, email: email ... }
```

Also, `$_POST['submit']` isn't defined. Instead, try using `$_POST['username']` or something else from your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<style>
    body{
        outline: none;
        background-color:#222222;
    }

    select{
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border: 0 solid transparent;
        width: 100px;
    }

    table{
        margin-left: 850px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background:#EAEAEC;
        margin-top:0;

    }
    input{width:372px;height:34px;}
    .submit{background-color:white;border:0 transparent}
    .mjesec{position:absolute;margin-left:200px;}
    .dan{margin-left:40px;position:absolute;margin-top:-25px;}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function Registracija_ajax() {
        var username = $('.username').val;
        var password = $('.password').val;
        var passverif = $('passverif').val;
        var email = $('.email').val;
        var ime = $('.ime').val;
        var prezime = $('.prezime').val;
        var dan = $('.dan').val;
        var mjesec = $('.mjesec').val;
        var godina = $('.godina').val;
        var avatar_source = $('.avatar_source').val;
        var sex = $('.sex').val;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registration.php",
            data: "{username,password,passverif,email,ime,prezime,dan,mjesec,godina,avatar_source,sex}",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.loading_gif').css('display:inline');
            },
            success: function (response) {

                $('.response').html(response);



            }
        });

    }

</script>

<body>

        <table cellspacing="21">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="username" required="ddd" placeholder="username" class="username">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="password" type="password" required placeholder="password" class="password">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="passverif" type="password" required placeholder="password" class="passverif">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="email" placeholder="email" required class="email">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="ime" placeholder="ime" required class="ime">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="prezime" placeholder="prezime" required class="prezime">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="sex" class="sex" style="margin-left:40px;position:absolute;">
                            <option value="male">Muško</option>
                            <option value="female">Žensko</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="godina" class="godina" style="margin-left:200px;position:absolute;margin-top:-23px;">
                            <option value="0000">Godina</option>
                            <?php
                            $beggining_year = date('Y') - 13;
                            $end_year = '1975';

                            while ($end_year <= $beggining_year) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $beggining_year . '">' . $beggining_year . '</option>';
                                $beggining_year--;
                            }
                            ?>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="mjesec" name="mjesec">
                            <option value="0000">Mjesec</option>
                            <?php
                            $beggining_month = '1';
                            $end_month = '12';

                            while ($beggining_month <= $end_month) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $end_month . '">' . $end_month . '</option>';
                                $end_month--;
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="dan" name="dan">
                            <option value="0000">Dan:</option>
                            <?php
                            $beggining_day = '1';
                            $end_day = '31';

                            while ($beggining_day <= $end_day) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $end_day . '">' . $end_day . '</option>';
                                $end_day--;
                            }
                            ?>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="avatar" name="avatar" placeholder="Profile photo(link only)">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button value="submit" class="submit" onclick="Registracija_ajax()"  name="submit">Registracija</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
</body>
<div class="response"></div>
```

@Philip Sorokin ,you have the other file above.